# extend :after inline-block for the rest of the element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a `h3` tag with `:before` (a small square) and as `:after` I would like a line that extends for the rest of width.

both the `:before` and the `:after` are set to `display:inline-block` , so that I can set the width and height.

setting the `width:100%` for the `:after` breaks into a new line

just take a look here

http://jsfiddle.net/CTd2w/81/

p.s. I'm fine with a JavaScript solution

Comment: Just remember `:before` and `:after` isn't supported by IE6 and IE7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't use `:before` and `:after`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/CTd2w/83/

HTML:

```
<h3><span>Aktuell</span></h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 {
    border: 0px solid #860d0f;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    height: 13px;
}
span {
    background: #fff url(images/logo_square.jpg) 0 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #860d0f;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 5px 0 14px;
}
```

Comment: great cross-browser solution, and a nice way to move the border up, thx

Answer (score 1):

This is a kinda hacky JavaScript/jQuery solution, but it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/CTd2w/82/

```
var h3AfterCalculatedWidth = 
    $('h3').width()        /* total h3 width */
    - $('h3 span').width() /* nested span to determine text width */
    - 14                   /* :before width + margin */ 
    - 5                    /* :after margin */;

$('head').append('<style' + '>h3:after {width: ' + h3AfterCalculatedWidth + 'px!important}<' + '/style>');
```

`!important` should be unnecessary but included it anyway

Comment: You should mention that your code requires `<h3><span>...</span></h3>` to work. Was there any reason you chose `append` over `css`? `$("h3:after").css("width", h3AfterCalculatedWidth + "px");`

Comment: @Wex Yes, the nested `<span>` in the `<h3>` element helps to identify the width of the text.  In regards to `append` vs `css` - Attempting to use jQuery selectors with  `:before` and `:after` pseudo-codes won't work to my knowledge, so adding the `<style>` block was my alternative

Answer (score -1):

When you set display:inline-block on an element, the width of that element becomes as big as it needs to be to format the element, unless the element sets its width, in which case that algorithm doesn't apply - you set the width, that's what it is. Look up "shrink to fit algorithm" in the CSS spec for full details. So when you say width:100% you guarantee a line break.

Not sure if you can solve this problem ...